# How to add multilanguage to Laravel 5.3 using SESSION

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multilingual, laravel-routing

I want to add multilanguage support to my website, but I don't know, how to to implement it best. The Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization) is very rare, so I've done some research, but everyone seems to use a different solution and is using URLs with the language inside of it - for example like `example.com/en/pagename`.

I want an URL schema without a language tag. Something like this: `example.com/pagename`

Now, depending on the users language, the URL should be translated:

`example.com/pagename (english)`
`example.com/seitenname (german)`

The initial language should be detected by the browser settings / language. The user should also have the option to switch between the provided languages.

On my website, an user is able to register for an account. He will be able to save his preferred language in the database - let's say in the table `users` in the field `pref_lang`. To keep it simple in this case, it's just a string like "en" (english) or "de" (german).

Translating the routes is easy by creating language files like this:

```
// resources/lang/de/routes.php

return array(
    'contact'   => 'kontakt',
    'pagename'   => 'seitenname'
);
```

...and one for EN:

```
// resources/lang/en/routes.php

return array(
    'contact'   => 'contact',
    'pagename'   => 'pagename'
);
```

...combinded with such routes for example:

```
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.dashboard');
});

Route::get('/{contact}', function () {
    return view('pages.contact');
});

Route::get('/{pay2gether-system}', function () {
    return view('pages.pagename');
});
```

Now is only the question, how I can create such a "language switch" button, store the language from the browser settings / switch action or from the database in a SESSION and how I can re-use it for the routes and URLs in HTML `<a href="#">` tags?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this a couple times and it's quite easy to accomplish. Follow the steps below and if you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

1. Create a `language` column in the `users` table. This is how I've set it in the past, `$table->string('language')->default('en');`
2. Create a new middleware to detect the language change, ex:`SetLanguage`.
3. Add the middleware to the bottom of the `web` middleware group in `app\Http\Kernel.php`.
4. Paste the following inside the `handle` method.

   ```
   if ($request->has('language')) {
       if (auth()->user()) {
           auth()->user()->language = $request->language;
           auth()->user()->save();
       }
       App::setLocale($request->language);
   } elseif (auth()->user()) {
       App::setLocale(auth()->user()->language);
   }
   return $next($request);
   ```
5. Create a service provider and register it in your `config/app.php` and in the boot method paste the following code.

   ```
   view()->composer('template.name', function($view) {
       $languages = [];
       $folders = File::directories(base_path('resources/lang/'));
       foreach ($folders as $folder) {
           $languages[] = str_replace('\\', '', last(explode('/',$folder)));
       }
       $view->with('languages', $languages);
   });
   ```
6. Now in your `template.name.blade.php` you can loop through the languages that are available in your application.

In your drop-down you should use `{{ url('/') . '?language=' . $language }}` as the link when your looping through. You may change the `language` key to something else, but if you do, you'll also have to change it in the middleware.

Comment: Thank you, but where does Laravel read the first / default language from the browser, if it isn't set in the database yet? That's missing, or? Also: I don't want to store the language in the like `{{ url('/') . '?language=' . $language }}`, but in a cookie / session. Isn't that possible?

Comment: There's a default in the database, it's set to `en`. You can change it to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something in the Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->has('language')) {
        $path   = $request->path();
        $locale = $request->get('language'); 

        # save locale 
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::make(
            'language', $locale, 1440 // 24h
        ));

        # set locale
        \App::setLocale($locale);  

        return redirect($path)->withCookie(cookie('language'));
    }

    if ($locale = $request->cookie('language')) {
       \App::setLocale($locale);  
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now in the Providers:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('template.name', function($view) {
        $directory = base_path('resources/lang/');
        $languages = \File::directories($directory);
        $view->with('languages', array_map('basename', $languages));
    });
}
```

And in the view:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    @foreach ($languages as $lang)
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url()->current() . '/?language=' . $lang }}" title="">{{ $lang }}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I'm not quite sure if this is a best solution... Maybe somebody with more experience in Laravel can show us another solution

Comment: Code optimization is not really the point of the question, though. Are you referring to another answer? It's not clear enough.